# Ordered list of redux-form fields

Tags: redux-form

Do you know how can I get the ordered list of field names from given form? [Instance API](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#instance-api) has a property called "fieldList" and it's an array but it's not in correct order. (`ordered list = [firstFieldName, secondFieldName, ...]` so what I need is a list of field names in order they appear in my form - top to bottom)

Also the redux-form' action `'@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD'` is dispatching out of correct form order so I guess it's not what I need here...

(My redux-form version: **7.3.0**)

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with `redux-form` and also have checked its API, but didn't find a documented way for getting the fields in the way they appear in the form.

**However, here's how I would do it:**

> I'll create a Reducer, that will keep track of the fields in the order,
>   they are registered (appear in the form).

1. **We have very detailed action**. As you already mentioned - `@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD` action is dispatching out all the fields in process of being registered in the correct order. This action has the following payload:

   ```
   {
     type: '@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD',
     meta: {
       form: 'user'
     },
     payload: {
       name: 'firstName',
       type: 'Field'
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Create a reducer**. So I'll just create a Reducer, that will listen for all `@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD` actions. Something like that:

   ```
   // The reducer will keep track of all fields in the order they are registered by a form.
   // For example: `user` form has two registered fields `firstName, lastName`:
   // { user: ['firstName', 'lastName'] }
   const formEnhancedReducer = (state = {}, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
       case '@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD':
         const form  = action.meta.form
         const field = action.payload.name

         return { ...state, [form]: [...state[form], field] }
       default:
         return state
     }
   }
   ```
3. **Usage**. In order to get ordered fields by a form, you just have access the Store (state) formEnhancer property with the form name: `state.formEnhanced.user`.

Keep in mind that you have to consider some cases as `@@redux-form/DESTROY`, but I think it's a pretty straightforward implementation.

I would prefer to keep things simple and just subscribed to `@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD` and just change the reducer implementation a little bit, in order to prevent form fields duplication. So I will just validate if the form field is already registered and won't care for supporting `@@redux-form/DESTROY`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I have been able to retrieve an ordered list of form field names from a given form is via the registered fields stored in the redux form state using the connect HOC (Higher Order Component) from 'react-redux':

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

class Foo extends Component {

  render() {

    const {
      registeredFields,
    } = this.props;

    ...
    ...
    ...

  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {

  // retrieve the registered fields from the form that is stored in redux state; using lodash 'get' function
  const registeredFields = _.get(state, 'form.nameOfYourForm.registeredFields');

  // creating an object with the field name as the key and the position as the value
  const registeredFieldPositions = _.chain(registeredFields).keys().reduce((registeredFieldPositions, key, index) => {
    registeredFieldPositions[key] = index;
    return registeredFieldPositions;
  }, {}).value();

  return({
    registeredFieldPositions,
  });

};

// registeredFieldPositions will now be passed as a prop to Foo
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```